# why isn't Xcode identifying PFFacebookUtils?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

Xcode 6 beta is recognizing Parse but not PFFacebookUtils when i am trying to initialize both  in appdelegate.m

here is how i am doing the integration of Facebook SDK

i am using cocoa pods to add parse and Facebook to iOS project. i am using Xcode 6 beta.
i create pod file this way

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'Parse'
```

i run pod install at terminal and this downloads parse and Facebook SDK

Now i import parse in appdelegate.m

using

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

Comment: [Does this help](https://github.com/futuraio/ParseModel-iOS/issues/1) ?

Comment: Did you follow the link I provided ?

Comment: ok sorry i just saw the hyperlink. will go through it and get back

Comment: Same issue here. It seems to have been introduced with v1.2.21 support (regression from 1.2.20 where it worked) in the podspec. Looking at the [change log](https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads) for 1.2.21 it looks like there is a new framework introduced that isn't referenced in the pod spec. Maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With v1.2.21 of the Parse library, `PFFacebookUtils.h` has moved into another Framework, `ParseFacebookUtils`. Xcode isn't recognising PFFacebookUtils.h because it most likely doesn't exist anymore.

You need to add the ParseFacebookUtils pod to your Podfile:

```
pod 'ParseFacebookUtils', '~> 1.2'
```

BUT, there is an issue with this. The Parse pod spec lists `Facebook-iOS-SDK` v3.17 as a dependency, and the `ParseFacebookUtils` spec lists an alternative Parse podspec (`Parse-iOS`) as well as `Facebook-iOS-SDK` v3.9.0 as a dependency, which is obviously a conflict. You don't need 2x parse libraries, and incompatible versions of the Facebook SDK floating around.

I've forked and updated a version of the `ParseFacebookUtils` spec on github, that solves both these  problems. If you'd like to use it add the following to your podfile:

```
pod 'ParseFacebookUtils', :podspec => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rickerbh/ParseFacebookUtilsSpec/master/ParseFacebookUtils.podspec.json'
```

And be sure to

```
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

as well so your project knows about `PFFacebookUtils`

Comment: thanks a lot!  #import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h> is the secret :)

Comment: the parse and Facebook iOS SDK versions your link downloads are quite old. How to change so that new ones are downloaded?

Comment: @user1406716 Just use the official Parse version now.